# how in gradle extract config fields to another gradle file

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I want to extract config fields from main gradle file into multiple gradle files. I have several build types, each with 15-20 fields. All this takes up a lot of space. I want to move assembly types to other files.

As it was before:

```
`subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        (extensions.findByName("android") as? com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension)?.apply {
            buildTypes {
                getByName("debug") {
                    debuggable(true)
                    resValue("string", "app_name", "dev")
                    resValue("bool", "is_test_branch", "true")

                    buildConfigField(
                        "String", "ENDPOINT",
                        "\"https://endpoint\""
                    )
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

What happened in the end:

```
`subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        apply(from = "debug.gradle.kts")
    }
}`
```

debug.gradle.kts:

```
`(extensions.findByName("android") as? com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension)?.buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
        debuggable(true)
        resValue("string", "app_name", "dev")
        resValue("bool", "is_test_branch", "true")

        buildConfigField(
            "String", "ENDPOINT",
            "\"https://endpoint\""
        )
    }
}`
```